# Semantic React / Button with text on left

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hello I have difficulty placing my button text on the left 
even using text-align left doesn't work with! important

```
      <ButtonStyled> Esqueci minha senha </ButtonStyled>
```

style:

```
export const ButtonStyled = styled(Button)`
background: transparent !important;
color: #000 !important;
text-align: left !important;
&:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #12b2ce !important;
}
`;
```

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-lake-grxyz

Comment: in your codesandbox, your button is wrapped by a div with classname `App` that has `  text-align: center;`

Comment: @Deve removing it does not make difference.

Comment: This has to do with the semantic css settings, but I can't fix it

Comment: It has two classes .ui.button
and
.button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
padding-left: 0 !important;
```

You styled button currently has 21px of padding assigned to it. Override that value.

Comment: I did not read the question properly. My bad. I updated my answer.